Не понимаю как получить сообщение в теме на форуме
Уже несколько часов пытаюсь понять. Я создал создание темы в ForumChannel через модальное окно в disnake хочу что бы жалобы на форуме проверяли только модераторы, а сам форум обычные пользователи не видели, так вот, после того как человек создает тему модератор может начать рассмотрение данной темы и я хочу что бы после сообщения в данной теме эти сообщения писались автору создания темы на форуме, я надеюсь что понятно обьяснил, если нет то задавайте вопросы, я попытаюсь более подробно расписать, вот весь код
from disnake.ext import commands

class ModalReport(disnake.ui.Modal):

    def __init__(self):
        components = [
            disnake.ui.TextInput(
                label='Введите ник нарушителя',
                placeholder='Введите никнейм нарушителя',
                custom_id='Никнейм нарушителя',
                max_length=32
            ),
            disnake.ui.TextInput(
                label='Суть обращения',
                placeholder='Введите суть обращения',
                custom_id='Суть обращения',
                style = disnake.TextInputStyle.paragraph,
                max_length=500
            ),
            disnake.ui.TextInput(
                label='Доказательства',
                placeholder='Вставьте ссылку на доказательства',
                custom_id='Доказательства',
                max_length=64
            )
        ]

        super().__init__(title='Создание тикета', components=components)

    async def callback(self, inter:disnake.ModalInteraction):
        chtosend = disnake.utils.get(inter.guild.forum_channels, name='「」на-дискорд')
        embed = disnake.Embed(title='Для модераторов', color=disnake.Colour.blue())
        view = StartView()
        for key, value in inter.text_values.items():
            embed.add_field(
            name=key.capitalize(),
            value=value[:1024],
            inline=False,
        )
        embed.set_thumbnail(url=inter.author.display_avatar)
        await chtosend.create_thread(name=f'Обращение от {inter.author}', embed=embed, view=view)
        await inter.send('Вы успешно создали обращение. Ожидайте его рассмотрения', ephemeral=True)
        await inter.send()
        

class ButtonView(disnake.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(timeout=None)


    @disnake.ui.button(label="Связаться", style=disnake.ButtonStyle.blurple, custom_id="button1")
    async def button1(self, button: disnake.ui.Button, interaction: disnake.Interaction):
        modal = ModalReport()
        await interaction.response.send_modal(modal=modal)

class StartView(disnake.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(timeout=None)     
           
    @disnake.ui.button(label="Начать рассмотрения", style=disnake.ButtonStyle.green)
    async def disable_button(self, button: disnake.ui.Button,interaction:disnake.Interaction):
        msg = f'**Модератор {interaction.author.mention} начал рассмотрение жалобы**'
        embed = disnake.Embed(
            description=msg,
            color=disnake.Colour.blue()
        )
        for child in self.children:
            if isinstance(child, disnake.ui.Button): 
                child.disabled = True
        await interaction.response.edit_message(view=None)
        await interaction.send(embed=embed)
class ButtonsRole(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.persistent_views_added = False

    @commands.command()
    async def forum(self, ctx):
        view = ButtonView()
        msg = 'Вы можете **связаться с модераторами и администраторами** при возникновении всевозможных проблем: начиная от обычных **вопросов**, заканчивая **жалобами** на пользователей'
        embed = disnake.Embed(
            title='Репорт',
            description=msg,
            color=disnake.Colour.blue()
        )
        await ctx.send(embed=embed, view=view)

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        if self.persistent_views_added:
            return
        self.bot.add_view(ButtonView(), message_id=1284956666290507927)

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(ButtonsRole(bot))


Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! как задать хороший вопрос => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
